# Get area and perimeter of 3D plane using JTS library

Tags: 3d, geotools, jts-topology-suite

is there any Java API in Geotools JTS lib for calculating area of 3D plane?
Same about Line, where points have three dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in general the difference in height between two points is negligible compared to the distance between them.

Comment: so I can consider only x,y during area, perimeter and lenght calculation, right?

Comment: depends are your polygons small and the mountains very big

Comment: Could an area of mountain surface be **much** bigger than 2D projection of mountain on a plane? 
https://matematikalegko.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/120.gif
Pyramid projection on the 2D plane could be much (3 and more times) smaller than actual pyramid surface.

Comment: Most mountains are a few 1000 metres but 10s or 100s km wide

Comment: Is it true for relatively small objects like house roofs, bridge slope?

Comment: clearly this assumption is not true for roofs, simple trigonometry will fix that.